# Unable to make program calculate correctly

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program which does a very basic calculation, but for some reason i can't get the code right. It is supposed to calculate the miles per gallon for one trip. You can then add this info multiple times (for different trips) and for each time it should calculate the total miles per gallon (i.e. the average miles per gallon of all the trips). This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int counter = 1;
double milePerRe, milePerTo = 0, x, y;
cout << "Enter the miles used (-1 to quit): ";
cin >> x;
cout << "Enter gallons: ";
cin >> y;
while (x != -1)
{
      milePerRe = x/y;
      milePerTo += milePerRe;
      milePerTo /= counter;
      cout << "MPG this tankful: " << setprecision( 6 ) << fixed << milePerRe;
      cout << "\nTotal MPG: " << setprecision( 6 ) << fixed << milePerTo << endl << endl;
      counter++;
      cout << "Enter the miles used (-1 to quit): ";
      cin >> x;
      if (x != -1)
      {
      cout << "Enter gallons: ";
      cin >> y;
      }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

When I run the program and say I enter 10 on the miles and 1 on the number of gallons the first time and the second time, everything works fine. Then if i do it again a third time the calculations begin to become incorrect.

Comment: Where are `milePerRe` and `milePerTo` declared?

Comment: How incorrect? Like in last decimal?

Comment: Why do `milePerTo` and `milePerRe` accumulate rather than reset on each loop?

Comment: Can you give a sample input/output and the incorrect output?

Comment: As is, it doesn't compile...  (cf Petar Minchev comment)

Comment: Sorry, the error Petar Minchev pointed out was something I forgot when I posted the question. I was going to change the variable name to improve program readability, but forgot to do so with the other variables in the code. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not calculate average of averages the way you do it. In your code you are dividing by the counter EACH iteration, while you should divide it only at the end.
Best way to do what you need is something like this:

```
...
double totalMiles = 0;
double totalGallons = 0;
...
while (x != -1)
{
     milePerRe = x/y;
     totalMiles += x;
     totalGallons += y;
     milesPerTo = totalMiles / totalGallons;
...
```

However, if your task was to explicitly calculate the average of trips (not the average of miles/gallons), you would need to introduce another variable, like this:

```
...
double currentMilesPerTo;
...
while (x != -1)
{
    milePerRe = x/y;
    milePerTo += milePerRe;
    currentMilesPerTo = milePerTo/counter;
    ....
    cout << "\nTotal MPG: " << currentMilesPerTo;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of x and y are not being updated properly i guess.after every iteration try to make x and y to zero.
hope it works this way

TNQ